# How To Write To Database User's Logout Timestamp When Browser Is Closed / Crash

Tags: php

I have a table on my database called 'Log'. This Log table contains ID, Username, LoginTime and LogoutTime. That's all.

It's really easy to INSERT into ID, Username and LoginTime columns...

But dealing with LogoutTime, I was thinking there will be 2 condition :

1. User click logout button >> PROBLEM SOLVED, I can easily put INSERT script on my logout.php to handle LogoutTime column.
2. User just run away from my website by clicking close button of their browser >> THIS WILL CAUSE A PROBLEM. How can I write to LogoutTime column in this situation like this?

can it be handle by PHP only? I mean, doesn't have to use jQuery... Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something similar to this, the time can be different according to your need

```
if (isset($_SESSION['browser_last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['browser_last_activity'] > 1800)) {
    // request 30 minates ago
    // set the logout time here
}
$_SESSION['browser_last_activity'] = time(); // update last activity time
```

But there is no way you can implement functionality 100% meet your requirements with php.

And with javascript you can try with `onbeforeunload`, it is good practice than do it with javascript and not in php because of overhead reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The most common solution to get this done is by using a timeout. So you run periodically a cron which checks whether there are users which are not active anymore. For example it can be no requests done for the last half hour. Then add the logout time at that moment.

So every action update the user session with the last request time so you know when they have a timeout.

Controlling 100% a closing browser is not possible. Think for example about a power failure at the client computer, you will get nothing back for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In IE you can try something like this:

```
< body onbeforeunload="alert('Closed!');">
```